# Google Analytics Funnel - How can I track any parameters in URLs

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

How can I track any parameters in URLs using funnels in Google Analytics?

In all product URLs one common string is "-pd-" so I need to track this and create a funnel with goal URL `/thankyou.php`

I am confused about step1. How can I evaluate the product page?

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expression matching in the URL and match the parameters in the URL.

Try using the Regular Expression Tester to see if your regex is correct
http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester

What are regular expressions?

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55582